# `Regex` on express get method

Tags: express

```
/* @Fix-me it`s looks ugly */                                                                                              
app.get(`/0.main_${version}.js`, (req: Request, res: Response) => sendZip(0, res))                                         
app.get(`/1.main_${version}.js`, (req: Request, res: Response) => sendZip(1, res))                                         
app.get(`/2.main_${version}.js`, (req: Request, res: Response) => sendZip(2, res))                                         
app.get(`/3.main_${version}.js`, (req: Request, res: Response) => sendZip(3, res))                                         
app.get(`/4.main_${version}.js`, (req: Request, res: Response) => sendZip(4, res))                                         
app.get(`/5.main_${version}.js`, (req: Request, res: Response) => sendZip(5, res))
```

This code look ugly, how I can improve it using `regex`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parameterize the number:

```
app.get(`/:num(\\d+).main_${ version }.js`, (req: Request, res: Response) => sendZip(req.params.num, res))
```

The `(\\d+)` part is optional, and is used to *only* match numbers, so `123.main_version.js` will match but `aaa.main_version.js` will not.

I'm not sure if you want to allow only a limited range of numbers. You could add an additional middleware that would validate `req.params.num` to make sure it falls within such a range.